# send a dataForm with a file in jquery ajax to php page

Tags: php, ajax

I built a back-end of a web application.  I want the client to use drag and drop to insert folders and photos in the server.

This is a snippet of the drag & drop function:

```
else if(item.isFile) {

var element = new FormData();

                element.append('foto', item);
                element.append('idMadre', id);

                $.ajax({
                url: '../php/model.php?az=dragDropElementoFoto',
                data:element,
                async:false,
                processData:false,
                contentType:false,
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json'
            })
            .done(function(data){
                let elem = document.createElement("li");
                elem.innerHTML = "<div class='row'><div class='col'><i class='fas fa-image'></i> "+item.name+"</div><div class='col-2'><i style='color:red' class='far fa-times-circle'></i></div></div>";
                container.appendChild(elem);

                })
```

In the PHP page, called "model.php," I have the code to make the typical C.R.U.D. operation with DB.  How can I use the item of the `FormData` on the PHP page?

This is the PHP code of model.php:

```
if($_REQUEST['az']=="dragDropElementoFoto") {


    $id=$_POST['idMadre'];
        $ogg=$_POST['foto'];
        var_dump($ogg);
    $uploaddir = "../img/catalogo/";
        $userfile_tmp = $_FILES['foto']['tmp_name'];
        $userfile_name = $_POST['foto']['name'];
        $urlfoto=$uploaddir.$userfile_name;
        if (move_uploaded_file($userfile_tmp, $uploaddir.$userfile_name)) {
            $sql="insert into documento (doc_url,doc_nome_file,doc_titolo,doc_cartella,doc_pub)"
        . "VALUES(:doc_url,:doc_nome_file,:doc_titolo,:doc_cartella,:doc_pub)";
    $dbo->query($sql);
    $dbo->bind(":doc_url", $urlfoto);
    $dbo->bind(":doc_nome_file", $userfile_name);
    $dbo->bind(":doc_titolo", $userfile_name);
    $dbo->bind(":doc_cartella", $id);
    $dbo->bind(":doc_pub",0);
    $dbo->execute();

            $sql="select * from documento where doc_id IN (select MAX(doc_id) as doc_id from documento)";
            $dbo->query($sql);
            $risposta=$dbo->single();

    echo json_encode($risposta);
}
}
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: What do you mean _how can I use the item of the FormData_ ? you use it with $_POST id-foto

Comment: Yes, but I want the file. The client drop a photo.
I can take the name, and the id of the folder, but I want the file to put in the server...

Comment: This code have an error.

Comment: Edit your question with error. (così capisco)

Comment: I passed a photo from JS page to PHP page by $ajax.
Now, in PHP page I know how can I process files from a html FORM (with $_FILES[]), but in this case I can't because there aren't input file...

Comment: Riesci ad accettarmi la risposta dato il lavoro fatto?

Answer (score 1):

in your html do you have input foto/idmadre? and second you can decode json like

```
$data = json_encode( $_POST );
  if( json_last_error() != JSON_ERROR_NONE ){
   exit;
  }
  if (!isset($_FILES['image']) || !is_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])) {
   echo 'No file send...';
   exit;
  }
```

Next you can use like simple post.

Another example:

```
var myFormData = new FormData();
myFormData.append('pictureFile', pictureInput.files[0]);

$.ajax({
  url: 'upload.php',
  type: 'POST',
  processData: false, // important
  contentType: false, // important
  dataType : 'json',
  data: myFormData
});
```

Comment: $_FILES don't exist because I don't use a html input to take photo or folders...I use drag and drop in simple div.

Comment: `element.append('foto', item);` create automatic a POST variable. 
non vuol dir niente  `element.append('foto', item);` crea automaticamente un POST col nome foto. quindi puoi utilizzarlo come un normale input esempio:[LINK](https://www.codexworld.com/ajax-file-upload-with-form-data-jquery-php-mysql/)

Comment: Dico in italiano.
Non uso un <input type='file'>, non ho alcun <form> in HTML.
Ho un div a cui ho associato un evento di drag and drop. Quando l'utente droppa qualcosa nel div scatta la funzione che mi legge le cartelle e i file in esse contenuti. Ogni cartella ed ogni file vengono automaticamente salvati nel database mysql.
Ora, il mio problema è che non avendo un form non so come passare il file alla pagina PHP perchè l'array $_FILES non c'è. e quindi non riesco ad attuare la soluzione che mi hai proposto.

Comment: Non serve nessun form per fare quello che t'ho detto, ti ho postato un altro codice per farti vedere

Comment: purtroppo non mi funziona. penso di sbagliare qualcosa

Comment: Il mio problema è che l'item che io inserisco nel FormData() è un oggetto FileSystemFileEntry e non riesco a gestirlo in PHP. non so proprio come fare.

Comment: Dai un occhiata qua: [LINK](https://www.html5rocks.com/it/tutorials/file/filesystem/)

Comment: Ti ringrazio molto della disponibilità, purtroppo penso che la strada da me intrapresa sia proprio sbagliata alla radice. Non dovevo usare i FileSystem per gestire il droppaggio...
Io riesco a creare il file ma poi mi risulta difficile gestirlo nella pagina PHP...cioè nella pagina dove realmente lo salvo nella cartella del server.

Comment: Ma l'output js è in blob oppure base64?